# For SharePoint Online, why aren't all the sites within my Hub Collection using the Hub's theme colors?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom, theme

We have a Hub Site Collection within SharePoint Online. We have also created a custom theme for our collection which is visible and working great on most of the sites.

But, there are a few sites within our collection that are still using the default Blue/White theme. When I go to those site's "change the look > theme" settings, the menu says "Your site is connected to the  hub site and is set to automatically adopt the same theme."

Even though I get this status message and my theme is working on most sites there a few still not taking on the colors. Are there any settings on specific sites that I'm missing that are causing this override?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it take anywhere from a couple hours to several days for custom themes to update on associated sites.

If it's still stuck, you can try re-associating the site with the hub. That should trigger the background process that copies the theme over.